# Read several lines from file at once

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

The following code works just fine:

```
Function ReadLines(FN As String, n As Integer) As String()
    Dim T(0 To n) As String
    With My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(FN)
        For i As Integer = 0 To n
            T(i) = .ReadLine()
        Next
    End With
    Return T
End Function
```

However, if the file is located on a distant server, this might prove horrendously slow. Is there a way to do the same more efficiently? I could read the whole file at once too, but this also is fairly inefficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`BufferedStream` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx) is specifically designed to reduce the number of system IO when a file is read (or written) sequentially in a series. So this is expected to make your reads more effective:

```
Function ReadLines(FN As String, n As Integer) As String()
    Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Using bs As New BufferedStream(fs)
            Using sr As New StreamReader(bs)
                Dim lines = New List(Of String)(n)
                For i As Integer = 0 To n
                    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
                    If (line Is Nothing) Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    lines.Add(line)
                Next
                Return lines.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't test its efficiency yet, but you need to add a fs.close , or your file will remain locked

Comment: I believe `Close()` will be invoked by `Dispose()`, which is called implicily at `End Using`

Comment: Well it doesn't seem so... At least not in my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadLines(fileName).
                    Skip(firstLineIndex).
                    Take(lineCount).
                    ToArray()
```

Unlike the `File.ReadAllLines` method, `File.ReadLines` doesn't read the whole file in a single operation.  It exposes the contents of the file as an `Enumerable(Of String)` but doesn't read anything from the file until you use it.  That code will have to read every line up to the last one you want but won't read anything beyond that.

To be honest, I'm not sure how much quicker it will be though, because it might actually use `StreamReader.ReadLine` under the hood.  It's worth testing though.  The alternative would be to just read larger chunks of the file and break it into lines yourself, stopping when you've read at least as much as you need.

Comment: The `FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader` returns a `StreamReader`, so I believe `File.ReadLines(...).Take(N)` is effectively the same as calling `.ReadLine()` `N` times as in the OP code snippet. Thus `File.ReadLines(...).Take(N)` adds nothing to performance. Though your code is definitely more concise and beautiful.

Comment: It does not compile in my environment ("take" is not recognised), but if @DmitryEgorov is right it is not useful anyway...
About reading larger chunks, this could be of use indeed. How do I read a certain number of chars?